# Ford Sport Trac has no reverse

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, sport-trac

On a 2010 Sport Trac 4.0 I have no reverse. My trans slip ratio still reads when in reverse and not moving. Would this be as simple as a Manual lever position sensor gone bad or a problem with the band?

Comment: What does "...trans slip ratio still reads..." mean?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - I believe the "ratio" is the difference between input and the output of the transmission. Until torque converter lockup, there are always losses. If the slip ratio exceeds a certain amount, this is telling computer there is too much slippage. This could happen at speed or at a stand still.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Thanks, makes sense. How would one "read" the slip ratio? What is the OP looking at?

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica - I would bet the OP is getting a powertrain DTC which is telling them there's an issue. Reading through a couple of things, the computer uses the TSR when computing max tip-in torque rate. At this point, you know as much as I do.

Answer (score 1):

If there is too much slippage read by the computer, it wouldn't be because of the selector lever position. This pretty much leads to either the reverse band going out, or the reverse solenoid having issues. It could possibly be because of low line pressures, but since you're getting the error only in reverse, it sort of precludes this.